# log writing failed. "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing rails based api and I used to always get this warning, log writing failed. "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8. 
Does any body have any idea why this warning appears?